# Rails SQL query being turned into a COUNT

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails

I have this code:

```
@people.count
```

Which produces a query beginning with:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ( SELECT * .....
```

And this error:

```
column "peoplerelationships.updated_at" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 5:    ORDER BY    peoplerelationships.updat...
```

If I query just `@people`, there is no error. By requesting a `COUNT` it introduces an aggregate function to the query and hence the error. Can you ensure `@people` is evaluated first, and then counted? How do you do this properly?

Comment: What does the `@current_matches_unordered.to_sql` query output?

Comment: Actually the result set of that query is empty, would that affect things?

Comment: No the result set doesn't matter, I just wanted to know if you output the result of `@current_matches_unordered.to_sql`, what does the query look like. So what does `puts @current_matches_unordered.to_sql` ouput?